# cvlc single file play on multiple call

Tags: bash, audio, vlc

Good morning, i'm encountering problems with cvlc and Ubuntu 13.10.

I've lot calls to cvlc but each time i want reproduce only the first one , and than reproduce the first that come after  that one is over (not the other that may be come in the meantime).
The calls have to invoke VLC via command line.

In the past i was using the following command in my script:
"DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/local/bin/cvlc " + PATH + voiceFileName + " --play-and-exit &"

but in the last times, when i do it , all audio traks go reproduced concurrently.

Hope someone can help.
Tx for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It is caused form a known bug as told me by a developer on the VLC forums. Use this line instead: DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/local/bin/cvlc " + PATH + voiceFileName + "--one-istance --playlist-enqueque --play-and-stop --play-and-exit &" Hope it can help someone else.